# For-loop saving state with closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, closures

Forgive me if this might be a bit of a noobie question, but this should work shouldn't it?

```
var elems = [1,2,3,4,5]

for (var i = 0; i <elems.length; i++) {
    return (function(e){
        console.log(e)
    })(i);
}
```

Meaning, it should spit out

```
>>node file.js
1
2
3
4
5
```

For some reason this isn't doing this. Rather when it is run in terminal, it spits out

```
>>node file.js
1
```

What am I missing? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: A `return` outside of a function? I wonder how that is not a syntax error.

Comment: Related question - [Why does a module level return statement work in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955047/1903116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are returning the value returned by the IIFE immediately, in this statement

```
return (function(e){
    console.log(e)
})(i);
```

since the IIFE just prints `0` and doesn't return anything explicitly, JavaScript will return `undefined` by default and exit immediately. To fix this, just drop the `return` keyword,

```
(function(e){
    console.log(e)
})(i);
```

---

**PS:** Have you ever wondered, why the `return` statement in the above code works? To think about it, it is not inside a function. Then technically its an error, right? ;-) I explained this in detail, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28955047/1903116).

Answer (score 2):

When you call the return, it will immediately break out of the loop. If you want to return all the values, you will have to put them in a container and return the container.