# Why does a module level return statement work in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, syntax-error, node-modules

When I was answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28953795/1903116) I came across a Node.js module with a top-level `return` statement. For example:

```
console.log("Trying to reach");
return;
console.log("dead code");
```

This works [without any errors](http://ideone.com/PLbu80) and prints:

```
Trying to reach
```

in the standard output but not "`dead code`" - the `return` actually ceased execution.

But according to the [specification of `return` statements in ECMAScript 5.1](http://es5.github.io/#x12.9),

> **Semantics**
>
> An ECMAScript program is considered *syntactically incorrect if it contains a return statement that is not within a `FunctionBody`*.

In the program shown above `return` is not within any function.

**Then why doesn't this throw?**

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The modules are wrapped by Node.js within a function, like this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    // our actual module code
});
```

So the above shown code is actually executed by Node.js, like this

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    console.log("Trying to reach");
    return;
    console.log("dead code");
});
```

That is why the program prints only `Trying to reach` and skips the `console.log` following the `return` statement.

## Internals

This is where we need to understand how Node.js processes Modules. When you run your .js file with Node.js, it treats that as a module and compiles it with the v8 JavaScript engine.

It all starts with [`runMain` function](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L501-506),

```
// bootstrap main module.
Module.runMain = function() {
  // Load the main module--the command line argument.
  Module._load(process.argv[1], null, true);
  // Handle any nextTicks added in the first tick of the program
  process._tickCallback();
};
```

In the [`Module._load`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L275) function, a [new Module object is created](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L300) and [it is loaded](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L312).

```
var module = new Module(filename, parent);
...
...
try {
  module.load(filename);
  hadException = false;
```

The [`Module` function's `load` does this](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L346),

```
// Given a file name, pass it to the proper extension handler.
Module.prototype.load = function(filename) {
  debug('load ' + JSON.stringify(filename) +
        ' for module ' + JSON.stringify(this.id));

  assert(!this.loaded);
  this.filename = filename;
  this.paths = Module._nodeModulePaths(path.dirname(filename));

  var extension = path.extname(filename) || '.js';
  if (!Module._extensions[extension]) extension = '.js';
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
  this.loaded = true;
};
```

Since our file's extension is `js`, we see what the `Module._extensions` has for `.js`. It can be seen [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L477)

```
// Native extension for .js
Module._extensions['.js'] = function(module, filename) {
  var content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
  module._compile(stripBOM(content), filename);
};
```

The `module` object's `_compile` is invoked in that function and [this is where the magic happens](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L376),

```
// Run the file contents in the correct scope or sandbox. Expose
// the correct helper variables (require, module, exports) to
// the file.
// Returns exception, if any.
```

**This is where the [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_require) function, used by our node modules's is created first.**

```
function require(path) {
  return self.require(path);
}

require.resolve = function(request) {
  return Module._resolveFilename(request, self);
};

Object.defineProperty(require, 'paths', { get: function() {
  throw new Error('require.paths is removed. Use ' +
                  'node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH ' +
                  'environment variable instead.');
}});

require.main = process.mainModule;

// Enable support to add extra extension types
require.extensions = Module._extensions;
require.registerExtension = function() {
  throw new Error('require.registerExtension() removed. Use ' +
                  'require.extensions instead.');
};

require.cache = Module._cache;
```

And then there is something about wrapping the code,

```
// create wrapper function
var wrapper = Module.wrap(content);
```

We set out to find what `Module.wrap` does, [which is nothing but](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L64)

```
Module.wrap = NativeModule.wrap;
```

[which is defined in `src/node.js` file](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/src/node.js#L794-801) and that is where we find this,

```
NativeModule.wrap = function(script) {
  return NativeModule.wrapper[0] + script + NativeModule.wrapper[1];
};

NativeModule.wrapper = [
  '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
  '\n});'
];
```

**This is how our programs have access to the magic variables, `exports`, `require`, `module`, `__filename` and `__dirname`**

Then the wrapped function is compiled and executed [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L445) with [`runInThisContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_options),

```
var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, { filename: filename });
```

And then finally, the module's compiled wrapped function object is invoked like [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L461), with values populated for [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_exports), [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_require), [`module`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_module), [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_filename) and [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_dirname)

```
var args = [self.exports, require, self, filename, dirname];
return compiledWrapper.apply(self.exports, args);
```

This is how our modules are processed and executed by Node.js and that is why the `return` statement works without failing.

Comment: This does not apply to Vite and ESBuild based tools... they will error out... https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/v0.14.48/internal/bundler/bundler_default_test.go#L1643

Comment: The final links do not work anymore: `populated for exports, require, module, __filename and __dirname`