# Missing function name in NodeJS stacktrace; why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

NodeJS v0.10.31 under OS X, same behavior under NodeJS v0.12.2.

My stack trace doesn't show the `test` function name when called normally:

```
function test() {
  throw new Error('Missing `test` in stack trace?');
}

try {
  test();
} catch (e) {
  console.trace(e);
}
```

Output:

```
Trace: [Error: Missing `test` in stack trace?]
    at Object.<anonymous> (no_stack_in_node.js:8:11)
    // etc.
```

If it's inside a `setTimeout` I see what I expect:

```
try {
  setTimeout(test, 0);
} catch (e) {
  console.trace(e);
}
```

Output:

```
Error: Missing `test` in stack trace?
    at test [as _onTimeout] (no_stack_in_node.js:2:9)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

In the browser I see the latter in both cases.

Is there something specific I'm missing, or is the environment of NodeJS's CLI interfering, e.g., the "top level object" behaves a bit differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node.js, all the code in a module will be wrapped in an anonymous function, like this

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    // our actual module code
});
```

So your actual code will be wrapped like this

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    function test() {
        throw new Error('Missing `test` in stack trace?');
    }

    try {
        test();
    } catch (e) {
        console.trace(e);
    }
});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955050/1903116) for a detailed explanation.

So, when you are tracing the location of the `e`, it actually is in an anonymous function. That is why it says `Object.<anonymous>`

Comment: Shouldn't the `test()` function still be somewhere in the stack trace? The code **does** throw from within it - it should be right next to the anonymous function.

Comment: @RobertRossmann `test` has thrown the exception, the stack unwinds and `test` will not be in the stack at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace `console.trace(e)` with `console.log(e.stack)`, and you will get:

```
Error: Missing `test` in stack trace?
    at test (no_stack_in_node.js:2:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (no_stack_in_node.js:8:11)
```

When you do `console.trace` you print the stack trace of the place where you are (it is not required that the object is an error, you can just say `console.trace('hello')`), that is, inside the `catch` block.

If you want to get the stack trace of the error, you must read the trace from it (`e.stack`). Once read, you can log it, or whatever you need.