# `this` in global context and inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

According to [this explanation in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

- in the global context, `this` refers to the global object
- in the function context, if the function is called directly, it again refers to the global object

Yet, the following:

```
var globalThis = this;
function a() {
    console.log(typeof this);
    console.log(typeof globalThis);
    console.log('is this the global object? '+(globalThis===this));
}

a();
```

... placed in file `foo.js` produces:

```
$ nodejs foo.js 
object
object
is this the global object? false
```

Comment: Try adding `console.log(this);
    console.log(globalThis);` to see what they actually are

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Node.js, whatever code we write in a module will be wrapped in a function. You can read more about this, in this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955050/1903116). So, `this` at the top level of the module will be referring to the context of that function, not the global object.

You can actually use [`global` object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global), to refer the actual global object, like this

```
function a() {
  console.log('is this the global object? ' + (global === this));
}

a();
```

Comment: Given that `a` is called from within the module though, shouldn't it stil be the same inside and outside the function?

Comment: @JamesThorpe `a` is called without any context object (`this`). So, by default `this` will refer the global object only.