# Break execution from function

Tags: javascript

Is possible to break execution program from function or I need to check boolean val returned?

Code

```
function check(something) {

    if (!something) return;
    // Else pass and program continuing
}

check(false); // I want to stop execution because function has returned
// Or I need to check value like if (!check(false)) return; ?
// I want easiest possible without re-check value of function..

alert("hello");
```

Comment: A way to stop execution from function, without re-check returned value of it...

Comment: You can only `return` if you're in a function. There's no way to do that from top-level script code.

Comment: @Barmar [unless you are using Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955047/1903116) :D

Comment: @barmar what about throw 

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to through an Error, but otherwise you would need to use a boolean check, yes. I would recommend to use the boolean

```js
function check(something) {

    if (!something) throw "";
    // Else pass and program continuing
}

check(false); // I want to stop execution because function has returned
// Or I need to check value like if (!check(false)) return; ?
// I want easiest possible without re-check value of function..

alert("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest...

```
(function(){
  function check(something) {

    if (!something) return false;
    // Else pass and program continuing
  }

  if(!check(false)) return; 

  alert("hello");
});
```

`(function(){ ... });` is called [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) Immediately-invoked function expression.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in an IIFE, then you can use `return`

```
(function() {
    function check(something) {
        if (!something) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (!check(false)) {
        return;
    }

    alert("hello");
});
```