# modules.exports is the same as "this" in CommonJs?

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I accidentally used `require()` on a javascript module meant to be used with the browser.
The module set `this['libraryName'] = ...`.
I noticed that it actually *worked*.

So, I created 2 files:

`test1.js`

```
console.log( require('./test2.js'))
```

`test2.js`

```
console.log(this === module.exports)
this.SOMETHING = 10
```

The result?

```
$ node ./test1.js 
true
{ SOMETHING: 10 }
$
```

I didn't expect this!
That `true` means that module.exports is the SAME as `this` in the global context.

- Is that new?
- Is that part of the specs?
- Doesn't this make it immensely easier to create files that will work if they are imported OR required?
- If this works, why do we still do the whole check `typeof require === 'undefined'`?

  - Have I been oblivious to something this important for *years*?

Comment: Hey this is most probably because require() invokes the module cache, which is why it looks like it is emulating  that it is global  [you can read the last paragrap here about it](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)

Comment: I am not sure what the module cache has anything to do with it, and the last paragraph is unrelated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This isn't new:

   1. [What is the 'global' object in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627622/what-is-the-global-object-in-nodejs)
   2. [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions)
   3. [Why does a module level return statement work in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955047/why-does-a-module-level-return-statement-work-in-node-js/28955050#28955050)
   4. etc.
2. It's not part of the specs https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

   > That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node.js this is **different**.

   When some things are different they are most definitely not part of any spec.
3. > Doesn't this make it immensely easier to create files that will work if they are imported OR required?

   Don't see how. In node.js `this.SOMETHING = 10` only changes one name (`module.exports`) for another (`this`). Nothing more.
   And if you'll try to import `test2.js` into the browser using webpack or `<script type="module" src="..."></script>` you will get `TypeError: undefined has no properties` in both cases.
4. > `typeof require === 'undefined'`

   Maybe you would be better off with `browser-require`, `browserify` or something like that.