# Evaluate a "custom test" file in a safe scope with access only to chosen local variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, eval

**Context**

I am writing a "testing" utility for a specific use case.

We need the tests to be in separate files, and to be really simple to write, inspired by cypress and mocha.

For now I load the tests using `require` and it works well, but for the tests to be even more simple, I'd like to remove the first and last lines which are redundant.

**What I have**

```js
// test.file.js :
const test = new (require("../index.js").Test)()
// to be removed

test.this(true)   // test is initialized
  .should("equal", true)  // (syntax inspired by cypress)

test.log(__dirname) 
// all node functionnalities (require...)
// are available

module.exports = test // to be removed
```

```js
// importing logic :
function run (filePath) {
  const test = require(filePath)
  test.run()
} // much simplified
```

Here everything works fine but you need to require the library and do some logic and export the test in each test file.

**What I would like**

```js
// test.file.js
test.log("hello world")

test.this(true)   // test is initialized
  .should("equal", true)

test.log(__dirname)  // node functions are available
```

Here `test` is already declared, initialized and available at scope level.

Exports are also automatic.

**The problem**

I'd like all node core functionalities to be available in the test BUT not the scope variables where I import the file.

**What I tried**

I achieved to make it work using some complicated `eval`, but the problem is that every local variables of the parent scopes are available for modification in the tests...

```js
let hello = "world"
// this variable should not be available in the test

function run (testPath) {
  const test = new Test()
  // initialize the test

  const script = readFileSync(
    resolve(__dirname, testPath),
    {encoding: "utf-8"}
  )
  const scope = {
    test
  } // local variables i want the function to have access to

  eval(
    "(function ("
    + Object.keys(scope).join(", ")
    + ") {"
    + script
    +  "})"
  )(...Object.values(scope))

  console.log(hello)
  // here hello can be modified inside the test
  // this I don't want

  test.run() // works
}
```

I also tried with `new Function(script)` and some derivative but I could not find a solution

**Question**

How could I evaluate the test file in a clean node scope, scope with ALL the node functionalities AND only one shared variable which is `test` ?

Minimum reproducible example:

```js
// test.file.js

test.log("hello from test")
test.variableProperty = "MODIFIED"
test.log(__dirname) // global node available
// test.log(hello) // should crash or hello be undefined
```

```js
// index.js

class Test {
  constructor () {
    this.variableProperty = "INITIAL"
  }
  log (str) {
    console.log(str)
  }
  run () {
    console.log(this.variableProperty)
  }
}

// file import logic :
function importTest (path) {
  const test = new Test()
  // ...
  return test
}

// testing :
let hello = "should not appear"
const t = importTest("./test.file.js")
t.run()
// should output:
// "hello from test"
// (the __dirname)
// "MODIFIED"
// (and crash if last line of test.file.js uncommented)
```

Comment: a) just make these values global and use `require` as normally b) look at [the implementation of `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955050/1048572) and replicate it (or the parts that you need), adding the values you want to have in scope. For a simple version, see also [the `scope` parameter in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032179/1048572)

Comment: tank you for your 3 solutions and for pointing me to this excellent and detailed answer, I'll give a try to each solution